# Move Null rows to the bottom of the dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 10, np.nan, 5, 6, np.nan, 8],
                   'b': list('abcdefgh')})
df1

     a      b
0   1.0     a
1   2.0     b
2   10.0    c
3   NaN     d
4   5.0     e
5   6.0     f
6   NaN     g
7   8.0     h
```

I would like to move all the rows where a is np.nan to the bottom of the dataframe

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 10, 5, 6, 8, np.nan,  np.nan],
                   'b': list('abcefhdg')})
df2

     a      b
0   1.0     a
1   2.0     b
2   10.0    c
3   5.0     e
4   6.0     f
5   8.0     h
6   NaN     d
7   NaN     g
```

I have tried this:

```
na = df1[df1.a.isnull()]
df1.dropna(subset = ['a'], inplace=True)
df1 = df1.append(na)
df1
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this? Or is there a function that I can use for this?

Comment: Do you need sort or move?

Comment: I need to move the values

Comment: Ok, so `sort_values` cannot be used, right?

Comment: Maybe the best change data for not confused another people :)

Comment: This is indeed confusing. His output looks like sort_values with na_position

Comment: Yeah, changed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exist in `pandas` yet, use [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) with [`Series.argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.argsort.html) for positions and change ordering by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df1 = df1.iloc[df1['a'].isna().argsort()].reset_index(drop=True)
print (df1)
      a  b
0   1.0  a
1   2.0  b
2  10.0  c
3   5.0  e
4   6.0  f
5   8.0  h
6   NaN  d
7   NaN  g
```

Or pure pandas solution with helper column and [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df1 = (df1.assign(tmp=df1['a'].isna())
          .sort_values('tmp')
          .drop('tmp', axis=1)
          .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df1)
      a  b
0   1.0  a
1   2.0  b
2  10.0  c
3   5.0  e
4   6.0  f
5   8.0  h
6   NaN  d
7   NaN  g
```

Answer (score 4):

**New answer after edit OP**

You were close but you can clean up your code a bit by using the following:

```
df1 = pd.concat([df1[df1['a'].notnull()], df1[df1['a'].isnull()]], ignore_index=True)

print(df1)
      a  b
0   1.0  a
1   2.0  b
2  10.0  c
3   5.0  e
4   6.0  f
5   8.0  h
6   NaN  d
7   NaN  g
```

**Old answer**
Use `sort_values` with the `na_position=last` argument:

```
df1 = df1.sort_values('a', na_position='last')

print(df1)
     a  b
0  1.0  a
1  2.0  b
2  3.0  c
4  5.0  e
5  6.0  f
7  8.0  h
3  NaN  d
6  NaN  g
```

Comment: The new solution is similar to mine but definitely much cleaner. Thanks